# Is it possible to design a latch based FIFO instead of FF?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

A latch based fifo (i.e. level sensitive latch) might be cheaper in terms of area than FF based FIFO. I'm looking for a latch based FIFO design code or architecture. So far I didn't come across any. Is it possible to design one? I'm looking for some papers or idea to get started...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pulse latches](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1271447), which retain the [advantages of both latches and flip-flops](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5719582&tag=1), offering higher performance and lower power consumption, but they are not often "fully" supported by common CAD tools.

Alternatively, you can convert your flops into two level-sensitive [master/slave latches](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/03sp/pdfs/lectures/lecture17.pdf). A flip flop can be implemented by two opposite phase latches. This is usually done to enable time borrowing and does not necessarily result a smaller/faster circuit. This way your FIFO structure is very similar to the flop-based design, except that each flop is replaced by two latches.

Comment: Depending on what CAD tools he is using, using flip-flops at the RTL level will most likely get converted into master/slave latches in the layout. So the latter probably won't save much area.

Comment: @Zhehao Mao: Not sure if I agree. It depends on the std cell library you are using. flip-flops are commonly stand-alone cells in the library. No need for the CAD tool to convert them to master/slave latches. Internally, the flop cells might include master/slave latches, but their layouts are usually very optimized and smaller than two separate stand-alone latch cells.

Comment: That's true, but my point is that using master/slave latches to replace flip flops doesn't really satisfy @newbie's ultimate goal, which is to reduce area (in fact, by what you've said, it might actually increase the area).

Comment: I guess one way will be to to clock gate the storage cells where each cell is a latch. The cell will be loaded with data only when we receive a new data valid signal. If there is not new data to be written then all the cell of a row will be clock gated. I'm not quite sure if clock gating in a small scale worth much. I'm taking about a fifo of ~200 deep and ~128 width. Any comment on that? I might be wrong though...

Comment: @newbie: you need to make sure as you open the latch on one stage, the data in the next stage is not contaminated. This is done with latches by two-phase clocking. I don't think connecting latches all controlled by one clock, even in the presence of clock gating can achieve what you want. What if two consecutive latches are both enabled? In this case, once the clock is 0 or the enable is 0, they both hold the same value, i.e. the first latch acts as a wire instead of a memory element.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use latches for fifos, though I don't have any code handy to show how. Typically, I have seen fifos implemented as a 'sram' for the storage with a wrapper for the fifo logic around it. This structure can also handle different read/write clocks relatively naturally.

I don't know the exact heuristics, but I think

- small  sram cells are implemented using flops.
- medium sram cells are implemented using latches.
- large  sram cells are implemented using actual ram cells.

There is some crossover point between using flops and latches, where the extra overhead of control logic and routing for the latches becomes worth the area saving in the actual storage.